# Copy my website using IIS 7

Tags: iis

I just activated IIS 7 via Control Panel.
I want to copy an already built site, given from a friend of mine.
I use FileZilla to search to the server, and then copy the wwwroot file from the server to the wwwroot file to C:/Windows/intepub, folder (the IIS folder).
When I try to connect to localhost from Google Chrome, I just see a log of the wwwroot files, and besides I cannot open neither one of them (I am getting the "HTTP 403.14 - Forbidden" error), I don't want this.
I want to get the whole website **as it is**, and then make some changes to it.
Some people told me to try XAMPP, but my website is basically written on ASP.
I just want to know if I am missing something, or if anyone know how to copy my website by any means necessary! 
Thank you a lot!

Comment: Just copying the code files isn't enough to get a site working. You need to configure IIS to run it. If it's classic ASP you're talking about and not ASP.NET have a look [here](http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/running-classic-asp-applications-on-iis-7-and-iis-8), see how far you get and then come back to us with specific questions.

Comment: do I need some Windows Server to do it?

Comment: No. What OS are you on? There are instructions in there for doing it on Windows 8 too.

Comment: I did what I could, and I ended up facing this, when I type localhost:
An error occurred on the server when processing the URL. Please contact the system administrator.
If you are the system administrator please click here to find out more about this error.
I can't go further.

Comment: If you put a plain text or html file into the folder and try to access that can you see it. In fact you should set up a simple asp page an try to access that. Googling that message there are many possible causes and the best thing to do is to strip the setup back to a basic one and then work up from there.

Comment: I'll try this, but even if I make it, how will it be possible to see my full website on localhost for testing? All I suppose I will see is a list of my .asp files and not the whole site.

Comment: Because you're not familiar with how to configure IIS to run a website like this the best thing to do is to get a very simple example ASP page running correctly first and then you'll have a better idea of the steps to get the more complicated version set up. Try [this](http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/running-classic-asp-applications-on-iis-7-and-iis-8/scenario-build-a-classic-asp-website-on-iis)